# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException:

Tags: java, parsing, exception, bufferedreader, parseint

I am executing my code in java But I am getting number exception error everytime. Please help

```
class TestClass {
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
  BufferedReader inp = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(System.in));
  String input = inp.readLine();
  //Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  StringTokenizer stk = new StringTokenizer(input);
  int n = Integer.parseInt(stk.nextToken());
  int q = Integer.parseInt(stk.nextToken());
  int [] arr = new int[n];
  int [] st = new int [n];
  for(int i =0;i<n;i++){
    arr[i] = Integer.parseInt(stk.nextToken());
     st[i] = fib(arr[i]);

  }  
while(q>0){
    int l = Integer.parseInt(stk.nextToken());
    int r = Integer.parseInt(stk.nextToken());
     System.out.println(gcd(st,l,r));
    q--;
}
```

I am continuously getting error message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input
>   string: "3 2"     at
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
>     at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)     at
>   java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)  at
>   TestClass.main(Main.java:14)

Comment: What are your inputs and what is `fib()` and `gcd()`?

Comment: You are trying to parse number `3 2`. This is the error, you can't parse a string with whitespaces. Try using TryParse method for avoid exceptions, but if you have wrong input values like `3 2` program are not going to print a number...

Comment: I can't see any way to get that particular error from the program you've shown here.  Is there something you're not telling us?

Comment: Can you show the input you're feeding `System.in`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use split method instead:

Instead of:

StringTokenizer stk = new StringTokenizer(input);

int n = Integer.parseInt(stk.nextToken());

int q = Integer.parseInt(stk.nextToken());

Use:

**String in[] = input.split(" ");**

**int n = Integer.parseInt(in[0]);**

**int q = Integer.parseInt(in[1]);**